# How we get registration id from c2dm (Android)?

Tags: android, android-c2dm

On Android applications, how to get Registration Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the C2DM page. http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html#registering

At the bottom of the page there are links to an example app which uses C2DM.

Basically you need to declare a receiver to receive the registration_id from Google and then fire off a registration request like so:

```
Intent registrationIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
registrationIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0)); // boilerplate
registrationIntent.putExtra("sender", emailOfSender);
startService(registrationIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the C2DM documentation

This is the sequence of events that occurs when an Android application running on a mobile device registers to receive messages:

- The first time the application needs
  to use the messaging service, it
  fires off a registration Intent to a
  C2DM server. This registration Intent
  (com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER)
  includes the sender ID (that is, the
  account authorized to send messages
  to the application, which is
  typically the email address of an
  account set up by the application's
  developer), and the application ID.
- If the registration is successful,
  the C2DM server broadcasts a
  REGISTRATION Intent which gives the
  application a registration ID. The
  application should store this ID for
  later use. Note that Google may
  periodically refresh the registration
  ID, so you should design your
  application with the understanding
  that the REGISTRATION Intent may be
  called multiple times. Your
  application needs to be able to
  respond accordingly.
- To complete the registration, the
  application sends the registration ID
  to the application server. The
  application server typically stores
  the registration ID in a database.
  The registration ID lasts until the
  application explicitly unregisters
  itself, or until Google refreshes the
  registration ID for your application.